Wifi not working on ubuntu?
I recently updated to Unbuntu 24.04 LTS version. During that day everything worked fine but today I encountered a problem connecting to  my wifi, It no longer works. I restarted my computer, but I can no longer connect to the internet. Any Ideas how to solve this problem?

See https://askubuntu.com/q/425155/19626 for the minimum information needed for this question to be answerable.

''sudo iw list''

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I edited your question to improve clarity. Please read How do I ask a good question? And provide us more details.
